# Python asyncio read file and execute another activity at intervals

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I admit to being very lazy: I need to do this fairly quickly and cannot get my head round the Python3 asyncio module. (Funnily, I found the boost one fairly intuitive.)

I need to readline a file object (a pipe) that will block from time to time. During this, I want to be able fire off another activity at set intervals (say every 30 minutes), regardless of the availability of anything to read from the file.

Can anyone help me with a skeleton to do this using python3 asyncio? (I cannot install a third-party module such as twisted.)

Comment: An alternate option that may be less complex is to read the file synchronously and do the other work in a background thread via `threading.Timer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*asyncio* (as well as other asynchronous libraries like twisted and tornado) doesn't support non-blocking IO for files -- only sockets and pipes are processed asynchronously.

The main reason is: Unix systems have no good way to process files. Say, on Linux any file read is blocking operation.

See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tulip/MvpkQeetWZA

**UPD.**

For schedule periodic activity I guess to use `asyncio.Task`:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def periodic(reader, delay):
    data = yield from reader.read_exactly(100)  # read 100 bytes
    yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)

task = asyncio.Task(reader, 30*60)
```

Snippet assumes `reader` is `asyncio.StreamReader` instance.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realised this difference. But in fact, as I think I stated, I am reading a pipe.

Comment: Added snippet for periodic runner.
If you'll be more concrete about pipe object type (how you create/get that object) I can guess more.